# Multiple SharedPreferences are not being stored

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-lifecycle

I am working with SharedPrefrences. I have multiple shared preferences in pref. I am changing values 0 to n-1 in a loop while, other value is User Score. Maybe there is some problem with my using of commit(), but the value is not updated. Can you suggest what should I do?

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Scorepref", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

for (int i = 0; i < mQuestionBank.length; i++) {
    editor.putBoolean(Integer.toString(i), false);
    editor.commit();
}

mAnswered.setText( "0/" +Integer.toString(mQuestionBank.length));

mScoreval = 0;
mAnswered_count=0;

editor.putInt("User_score", 0);
editor.commit();

mScore.setText("0");
```

Comment: How do you know, it's not stored properly? Show us how you read those values.

Comment: [.commit](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#commit()) Note that when two editors are modifying preferences at the same time, the last one to call commit wins.

Comment: So you will end up with SharedPreferences containing only User_score value.

Comment: If you already did not know, use the shortcut, "Ctrl + Alt + L" on windows for code intendation.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show us the code how you're trying read the data from `prefs` but anyway in your case, if you're not able to read the data by `prefs.getBoolean` then you can iterate over `pref.getAll()` like:

```
    if (pref.getAll() != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mQuestionBank.size(); i++) {

            if (pref.getAll().get(String.valueOf(i)) instanceof Boolean) {
                final Boolean yourSavedBoolean = (Boolean) pref.getAll().get(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

Or if you need only one value then:

```
    if (pref.getAll() != null) {
        Boolean yourSavedBoolean = false;
        if (pref.getAll().get("0") != null && pref.getAll().get("0") instanceof Boolean) {
            yourSavedBoolean = (Boolean) pref.getAll().get("0");
        }
    }
```